# JavaScript Expression

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with this JavaScript expression?

```
+[[+!![]]+[+![]]+[+!![]]+[-~!![]+-~!![]-~!![]]+[-~!![]]+[+![]]+[+!![]]+[-~!![]+-~!![]]]
```

A friend sent it to me and asked me to copy and paste it in the browser console.

This is the result:

10162014

If anyone could explain this to me or at least point me to right references please. Thanks!

Comment: This is neither new or novel http://blog.avast.com/2013/02/14/malware-dollar-equals-tilde-square-brackets/ http://hackaday.com/2012/08/13/writing-javascript-without-using-any-letters-or-numbers/

Comment: To start with, remember that `true` is equivalent to `1` and `false` is equivalent to `0`. Also that an empty list (like `[]`) when converted to a boolean value if `false`.

Comment: I'd have a look at some of these question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%5B%5D%22

Comment: Refer [cheat sheets](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33349,33405)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First break out your code to this: `!![]` which returns true (!! is to convert to boolean) and now `+` converts to number so `+!![]` returns 1.

`![]` converts to false so `+![]` returns 0.

`~[]` returns `-1` and `~![]` also returns `-1`.

`~!![]` returns `-2`.

Now, `-~!![]` returns `2` and `-~![]` returns 1.

So, combining them all returns 10162014.

All about you to know is [~, !, +, & -](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/)

Answer (score 2):

`![] = false;` `#` as an expression, it's false due to the `!` operatory
`[] = true;` `#` as an expression, it's defined, so it's `true`

`+!![] = 1;` because `+true = 1;`
`+![] = 1;` because `+true = 0`, because using a `+` operator in JS converts the boolean to an integer ref

So what he's done is basically constructed a numerical value using `boolean` to `integer` conversion, and some grouping.

Answer (score 1):

`[+!![]]+[+![]]+[+!![]]`: `[]` is an empty array, which is truthy. `![]` is thus false, `!![]` is true. `+true` forces it to a number, as `1`. Similarly for `+![]` as `0` via `false`.

`[-~!![]+-~!![]-~!![]]`: `~` is a two's complement operator; `~1` is `-2`. Thus, this evaluates as `-(-2)+-(-2)+-(-2)`, which is `6`.

The remaining addends are analogous.

`array + array` will convert arrays to strings; thus `[1]+[0]+[1]+[6]...` will give the string `"1016..."`

The plus at start will convert it to a number.